# Usage of __AVX512F__ in Visual Studio for compiling code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, intrinsics, avx512

I want to use `__AVX512F__` to compile specific parts of the code.

```
   #ifndef __AVX512F__
       #undef flag1
   #endif
```

To use the flag I right clicked on my visual studio project and set the enable enhanced instruction set. Even though I was using an AVX512 machine the flag1 was still getting undefined. I then also tried to set the flag `__AVX512F__` in preprocessor directives after right clicking my proj file. But that also didnt work.

Should I do anything else to make this work and am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you talking about Visual Studio Code or Visual Studio the compiler.  There is a tag for Visual Studio Code, the IDE.  My understanding is that Visual Studio, the compiler, doesn't produce code for the AVX microcontrollers.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: "AVX" is a SIMD extension for x86, Advanced Vector Extensions.  AVX-512 is only supported on high-end x86 CPUs.  I assume this is MSVC (Visual C++), since it's weird about not defining ISA-support macros, and IDK if it has an option to promise that AVX-512 is available on the target CPU (vs. only in functions and code-paths that use AVX-512 intrinsics.)  Unlike GCC, in MSVC you don't have to enable AVX-512 to use intrinsics for it.  There is `/arch:AVX2` to enable that, but maybe still not one for AVX-512, unless that's changed recently.

Comment: @PeterCordes There is a `/arch:AVX512`  option in MSVC 17.5.1, I don't know the specific release it became available.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. This is MSVC. I added this /arch:AVX512 using the enable enhanced instruction set option as given here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/arch-x86?view=msvc-170. But as I told earlier in the question the __AVX512F__ flag didnt seem to work for some reason

Comment: I don't understand what your example is intended to be. Maybe it's    `#ifdef __AVX512F__       
#define flag1    
#endif`

Comment: Works for me on https://godbolt.org/z/5Tvx8Whzb with MSVC 19.14 and later (from VS2017 and later).  As @Blastfurnace said, using `-arch:AVX512`.  MSVC19.10 from VS2017 accepted `-arch:AVX512` and defined the macro but `_mm512_set1_epi32` was missing from its immintrin.h (at least in the Godbolt WINE install).  MSVC19.10 from VS2015 didn't recognize the option at all (check the error / warning output.)

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Am using VS2022

Comment: And also am trying to use the flag in a .h file( Am not sure if this is useful info or not)

Comment: `__AVX512F__` will be defined everywhere in a compilation unit compiled with `/arch:AVX512` (including in files that get `#include`ed), unless / until you `#undef` it.  If it's not defined in VS2022, you probably didn't actually enable that command line option, or for some reason it works differently from Godbolt.

Comment: `Enable  Enhanced Instruction Set :Advanced Vector Extensions 512 (/arch:AVX512)` can be found in the project properties. Note: Don't forget to select Active Configuration.

Comment: Hi, Thanks All. The AVX512F seems to be set irrespective of the machine configuration(processor supporting AVX512) if the compiler supports AVX512 and Enable  Enhanced Instruction Set :Advanced Vector Extensions 512 (/arch:AVX512) is set. To use the flags and use those flags defined based on I needed to set that option across all those project files in the solution.

Comment: Hi, @Srihari S Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: Sure will do the same. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks All. The AVX512F seems to be set irrespective of the machine configuration(processor supporting AVX512) if the compiler supports AVX512 and Enable Enhanced Instruction Set :Advanced Vector Extensions 512 (/arch:AVX512) is set. To use the flags and use those flags defined based on I needed to set that option across all those project files in the solution

Comment: That's correct, as far as I know, MSVC has no equivalent for `gcc -march=native` to enable all features supported by the machine you're running the compiler on.  MSVC is designed around making binaries to distribute, not to run on the computer they were built on.  Since AVX and AVX-512, they have added options that makes it use those instructions everywhere, not just in code using those intrinsics, but you still have to manually set your build to use features your own CPU has, if that's what you want to optimize for.